# What's the best way of replacing values across different columns of a data frame in terms of performance and code-cleanliness?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently working with `dplyr` for cleaning up a dataset, so I created a `tbl_df` from a `data.frame` whose columns are lists of `chr`.

```
> class(data)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

> lapply(data, class)
$var1
[1] "list"

$var2
[1] "list"

$var3
[1] "list"

$var4
... [and so on...]

> head(data)
Source: local data frame

  var1     var2    ...
1 <chr[1]> <chr[1]>
2 <chr[1]> <chr[1]>
```

Across those lists (corresponding to columns var1, var2, etc.) there are lots of chrs like `".."` indicating a missing value.

In order to clean that up, I decided to transform those `".."` into NAs the following way:

```
data[data == ".."] <- NA
```

The sentence works as expected but it does not take advantage of `dplyr` and the execution time seems too long.

**Is there a better way to do the same replacement, maybe using dplyr, so that the code runs faster?**

I'm pretty sure there is a good and fast way of replacing values across all columns (or a subset of them) of a `data.frame / tbl_df`.

Comment: Try with `mutate_each` and `replace` i.e. `filtered %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(.=='...'), NA)))` (not tested without a reproducible example)

Comment: How is this data created? The best way is probably to do it when you read the data in, using the `na.strings` argument of `read.table` or `read.csv` (or the `na` argument of `read_csv` if you're very current in the Hadleyverse).

Comment: In addition to @Gregor's comment,  you can check `library(readr)` (from the same team) where you can specify `na` argument.  https://github.com/hadley/readr

Comment: According to `microbenchmark`, the `data[data == ".."] <- NA` is much faster than using `mutate_each` + `replace` like `data %>% mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(. == '..'), NA)))`.

Comment: Without a reproducible example I'm skeptical of your data... it's very unusual that all of your columns would be of class `list`... compare to `sapply(mtcars, class)` or even `sapply(as.tbl(mtcars), class)`.

Comment: @Gregor I think the reason why the data frame has that strange structure could be the way the data is obtained. I hit an API endpoint with `httr` and then use `jsonlite` to transform the request content. What I can probably do is `unlist` every column before doing any data clean-up. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, `fromJSON` doesn't take an `na` argument, but `toJSON` does...  the `jsonlite` author might be willing to add the functionality to `fromJSON`.

Comment: @Gregor This conversation helped me find out about some arguments for `[to|from]JSON` functions. I was able to 'unbox' the response of the API call and avoid having lists as columns. As for replacing the `".."` strings I will retest the mutate_each approach with `microbenchmark` to see if it performs better without those lists, just for the record. Thanks for your help, I agree with the answer you provided even when this particular case is different: filling NAs when reading is the best approach when possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just gonna turn my comment into an answer. The best place to fill in NA values in terms of code-cleanliness is when you read it in. It also probably performs pretty well too.

If your data is in a flat-file, then however you read it in probably has an argument to identify how NA values are coded. In base, e.g., `read.table`, `read.csv`, `read.fwf`, it's called `na.strings`. In the `readr` package the argument is  `na` (this will be *much* faster if you're worried about performance). `data.table::fread` will also be fast, and also has a `na.strings` argument.

From a database source, I would recommend adding the coding into the database query itself, but `RODBC::sqlQuery` will also pass along a `na.strings` argument to `read.table`.